# C++ - cout flags work only for first output

Tags: c++, formatting, iostream

When i pass some data, output is similiar to `xxxxxxxx0x97 0x104 0x111 0x106 0x0`
Why cout formatting is affecting only first output?

```
void Dumper::hex(const unsigned char * data, size_t len) {

        cout << endl;

        ios::fmtflags f(cout.flags());

        /*
        cout.fill('0');
        cout.width(2);
        */

        cout.fill('x');
        cout.width(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            cout << "0x" << ((long)(data[i]) & 255) << " ";
        }

        cout.flags(f);
        cout << endl;

    }
```

Comment: The `width()` is being reset after the insertion. Use `std::setw` inside the loop.

Comment: BTW you are outputting "0x" followed by a value in decimal  , if you want to output in hex then do a `cout << std::hex`.

Answer (score 0):

The `width()` is reset to 0 by any operation using it. The basic idea is that it is unlikely to apply to multiple fields. In particular, it unlikely to apply to a value and a separator. Thus, the width should be set up prior to each value.

For you specific use I'd use `std::internal` and `std::showbase`. Also make sure use `unsigned` values for your two digit hex values: otherwise you'll get the sign extended.